# change text in another class by button

Tags: qt

I have 2 classes, in first class, I have a QPushButton and in second class I have a QLabel (I put it on "public") . I want to when user click on the button in first class, QLabel in second class will change text. I think I shounld write a function to do that, and when user click on the button, button will call this function, that is my function (in my opinion):

```
void A::buttonClicked(B *bClass)
{
    bClass->label->setText("Button was clicked!");
}
```

And this is way I call it by my button on first class:

```
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonClicked(B)));
```

But I don't know why when I click, the label on the second class not changed. How to I do that? and sorry my English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're trying to connect a signal with no parameters to a slot that requires one parameter:

```
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonClicked(B)));
```

You're probably getting a message when you run  your app that says something like `QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments`. So that wont work.

To solve this, you can just add a function in class `B` that will change the text of it's `QLabel`.

```
void B::changeLabelText(const QString &text)
{
   label->setText(text);
}
```

Then have a slot in class `A`, that calls the `changeLabelText(const QString &text)` function in class `B`, and connect it to the button's clicked signal:

```
   objectB = new B;
   connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(clickedSlot()));
   ...    

void A::clickedSlot()
{
   objectB->changeLabelText("Button clicked");
}
```

Remember to declare it as a slot in `A.h`:

```
public slots:
    void clickedSlot();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you have to make two connections

```
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonClicked());
connect(button, SIGNAL(clickedSomeButton(B)), this, SLOT(buttonClicked(B)));
```

In the slot buttonClicked()  do this

```
void buttonClicked(){

   emit clickedSomeButton(B);

}
```

While using `signal` and `slots` you have to keep in mind that a `slot` can have arguments equal or lesser than the signal it is connected to because of this reason your code is not working.

What you need to do is to create a slot for the clicked action of button one . Then in the slot you again emit one signal with the argument B ( This signal you need to define yourself ) which can be caught by the slot you mentioned i.e., `buttonClicked(B)`

For creating signal use this syntax

```
 signals:
    double clickedSomeButton(B &)
```

Comment: ie I have to create 2 functions with prototype buttonClicked() and buttonClicked(B *b) ? I don't understand line: SIGNAL(clickedSomeButton("B")) what is clickedSomeButton("B") ?

Comment: clickedSomeButtoin is a new Signal you have to define

Comment: @SanyamGoel I think he is confused because in your code, signal `clickedSomeButton(B)` is a member of the `button` object, which is probably a `QPushButton` type. It probably should be `this` instead of `button`.

Comment: @thuga Yes you are right but he didin't post the entire code so I was just guessing I should change it so it wont be confusing