# change text of QLabel in another class with button

Tags: qt

I have ever post a question at there: [change text in another class by button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129834/change-text-in-another-class-by-button) But it justs working when second class is create by first class. Now I have 2 classes, they're created sametime, so how to I connect with together? below is all my code, first class has a button, and second class has a label, I want to when user click on the button in first class, label in second class will be changed. They're put in stackWidget:

```
// file.h

#include <QWidget>
#include <QtGui>

class widgetA;
class widgetB;

class A : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit A(QWidget *parent = 0);
private:
    QComboBox* comboBox;
    QStackedWidget* stackWidget;
    widgetA *wa;
    widgetB *wb;
};

class widgetA : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    widgetA(QWidget *parent = 0);
public slots:
    void buttonClicked();
private:
    QPushButton* button;
};

class widgetB : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void labelChangeText(const QString);

public:
    widgetB(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QLabel* label;
};
```

And this's cpp file:

```
//file.cpp

#include "a.h"

A::A(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    comboBox = new QComboBox(this);
    comboBox->addItem(tr("Widget A"));
    comboBox->addItem(tr("Widget B"));

    wa = new widgetA(this);
    wb = new widgetB(this);

    stackWidget = new QStackedWidget(this);
    stackWidget->addWidget(wa);
    stackWidget->addWidget(wb);
    stackWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
    connect(comboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), stackWidget, SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));

    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(comboBox);
    layout->addWidget(stackWidget);

    setLayout(layout);
}

widgetA::widgetA(QWidget *parent):
    QWidget(parent)
{
    button = new QPushButton(tr("Click"));
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonClicked()));
    QHBoxLayout* lay = new QHBoxLayout;
    lay->addWidget(button);
    setLayout(lay);
}

void widgetA::buttonClicked()
{
    // what I have to do at there for call the function at widgetB class?
}

widgetB::widgetB(QWidget *parent):
    QWidget(parent)
{
    label = new QLabel("....");
    QHBoxLayout* lay = new QHBoxLayout;
    lay->addWidget(label);
    setLayout(lay);
}

void widgetB::labelChangeText(const QString text)
{
    label->setText(text);
}
```

P/S: sorry my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either pass a pointer of `widgetB` object to `widgetA`, or you can connect a signal from `widgetA` to a slot in `widgetB`.

Here's an example of the signal/slot option:

```
// widgeta.h
signals:
   void changeText(QString text);
```

-

```
// widgeta.cpp
void widgetA::buttonClicked()
{
   emit changeText("button clicked");
}
```

-

```
//widgetb.h
public slots:
  void labelChangeText(const QString & text);
```

-

```
// a.cpp
connect(wa, SIGNAL(changeText(QString)), wb, SLOT(labelChangeText(QString)));
```

Answer (score 1):

What hinders you to call wb->labelChangeText("some string") in widgetA::buttonClicked()? You have a pointer to widgetB in class A. And labelChangeText is public in class B. Just that it is a slot does not mean that you cannot call it as a normal method.