# Can i read value from QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, label

I now how to set value(number) but can i read that label in some variable. if can't read, in which similar widgets can i put value and read it. Any help would be halpful or someone has an other idea. Maybe like LCD number, spin box

Comment: Are you looking for a field where the user can type things ?

Comment: You can check this link ,I think it will help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163872/change-text-of-qlabel-in-another-class-with-button

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
QString text = someLabel->text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the documentation. [QLabel.text()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#text-prop)

EDIT:

```
QString text = theLabel.text();
//or with pointer
QString text = theLabel->text();
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried :

```
QString s = YourQLabel->text();
```

This should work, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Thelepaty mode on
```

You need to use editor widgets, for example [`QLineEdit`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlineedit.html) or `QTextEdit`. You may customize it via [QSS](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/stylesheet-examples.html#id-db26d8ca-c309-47bd-87ca-9bcf5e89d978) to look like a `QLabel`.

P.S. try to improve your English. It is hard to understand, what you are asking.

```
// Thelepaty mode off
```